# Error in changing fields of associative table in roles and mod_objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to realize roles system for accessing our software models. So I have two models and a binding model for these two.

Role (id, name), ModObject (id, name), ModObjectsRoles (role_id, mod_object_id, canCreate, canRead, canUpdate, canDelete). The last four fields are boolean.

Role model :

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authorization_role

  has_many :mod_objects_roles
  has_many :mod_objects, :through => :mod_objects_roles

  def change_role_permissions(mod_object_id)
    @tmp = self.mod_objects_roles.find_by_mod_object_id(mod_object_id) #I get from mod_objects_roles table the row with mod_object_id=34
    @tmp.canUpdate = false #change value of 'canUpdate' field to false
    @tmp.save              # and save it
  end
end
```

ModObject model :

```
class ModObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :mod_objects_roles
  has_many :roles, :through => :mod_objects_roles
end
```

And an associative, joining these two above, ModObjectsRole :

```
class ModObjectsRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mod_object
  belongs_to :role
end
```

The problem is, when I am trying to change ModObjectsRole models canCreate, canRead, canUpdate, canDelete fields to true or false values, it gives me error. I tried several ways for 3 days or more now. I can not find how to do this.

In RolesController I use this code :

```
class RolesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_role, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @role.update(role_params)
        @role.change_role_permissions(34) # this is where I am trying to test
        format.html { redirect_to @role, notice: "Hi"}
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @role }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @role.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I used mod_object_id as 34 in controller above just for test, just let me learn how to do it and I will try to handle the rest for myself :

This is the table version of ModObjectRole, table mod_objects_roles :

```
mod_object_id | role_id | canCreate | canRead | canUpdate | canDelete       
    34            1         TRUE      TRUE       TRUE       TRUE
    2             1         FALSE     FALSE      TRUE       TRUE
```

Please help me if anyone has experience with it.
Thank you in advance...

Update, the error I get is :

```
TypeError in RolesController#update

nil is not a symbol

Extracted source (around line #10):

@tmp = self.mod_objects_roles.find_by_mod_object_id(mod_object_id) #I get from mod_objects_roles table the row with mod_object_id=34
@tmp.canUpdate = false #change value of 'canUpdate' field to false
@tmp.save              # and save it
  end
end
```

Comment: You can use factories or fixtures instead of creating objects manually. It would be helpful if you show us an error message also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it. The error comes out because the model ModObjectRole did not have a primary key. So I had to use gem called composite_primary_key and set a composite primary key for it like (mod_object_id, role_id). And that is all ...

Thank you ...